# PyQT(also C++ QT binding) embedded urxvt terminal loosing focus

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4, rxvt

I have problem with embedding urxvt terminal within QT application. Below is simplified code example. When i create a QT window and embed urxvt terminal inside(by using -embed parameter), i have a problem with focus. When the window is created, the first click into window make focus on embedded terminal -> everything ok, But when i click into the window second time, the terminal seems to loose the focus, though normal keyboard and mouse input is still working. But the terminal itself seems to think, it has no focus. It seems, like events are still sent to the embed window, though it has no focus.
Same problem appears when using C++ QT bindings.

It is nicely visible when add setting to .Xdefaults(and running necessary xrdb -load .Xdefaults): URxvt*fading: -40

Here is simplified example:

```
import  sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class embterminal(QWidget): 

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(1,1,600,400)
        self.process = QProcess(self)

        self.terminal = QX11EmbedContainer(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.terminal)

        self.terminal.showMaximized();

        self.process.start('urxvt',['-embed', str(self.terminal.winId())])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = embterminal()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

Comment: Does this cause any problems? As you said, keyboard and mouse events are still passed on.

Comment: Yes, it is - actually since the embedded window thinks, it doesnt have focus - it behaves like that .. for example terminal cursor is no tblinking.. everything is grayed... etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [QX11EmbedContainer](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qx11embedcontainer.html#details):

> It is possible for QX11EmbedContainer to embed XEmbed widgets from
>   toolkits other than Qt, such as GTK+. Arbitrary (non-XEmbed) X11
>   widgets can also be embedded, but the XEmbed-specific features such as
>   window activation and focus handling are then lost.

So perhaps urxvt (or your version of it) does not support all the necessary features of the [XEmbed Protocol](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html).

A web search turned up [this comment](https://github.com/davidben/embedded-emacs/issues/11):

> urxvt -embed almost works. It claims to support it and everything, but
>   does not send [XEMBED_REQUEST_FOCUS](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html#id2925225) when you click in it. This means
>   there's no way to get focus back after it's lost it.

Comment: Crap, not what i wanna hear. But thank you anyway... this is one big dissapointment. Though strange is, that when using GTK it somehow works...